# How to get dev server proxy target inside app?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, proxy, webpack-dev-server, devserver

I'm using `iframe` in the app, I don't know how to proxy it's `src` via dev server, therefore I'm doing

```js
const origin = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? location.origin : 'http://192.168.1.2:8081'
```

to make the `iframe` work in development mode, `'http://192.168.1.2:8081'` is hard-coded here, I'm looking for a way to reuse the webpack dev server proxy target, an API like `getProxyTarget()`, but if the `iframe`'s `src` could be proxied, that's even better!

vue.config.js `devServer` config:

```js
{
  port: 8055,
  proxy: {
    '/api': {
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/api': '',
      },
      target: 'http://192.168.1.2:8081',
      ws: true,
      changeOrigin: true,
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: The point of having the proxy is that the app doesn't have to know where the requests are really going. What's the context, why do you want to access the target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating an environment variable:

```sh
VUE_APP_PROXY_TARGET='http://192.168.1.2:8081'
```

and use it inside the app:

```js
process.env.VUE_APP_PROXY_TARGET
```